# Grails http url to use https

Tags: grails, https, spring-security

I have an application that runs on tomcat in amazon ec2. Both http and https are working. I want to use only https, such that when http://app.com is accessed, it will be redirected to https://app.com.

In SpringSecurity using spring it has an interceptor:

```
<sec:http auto-config='false'>
     <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https"/>
</sec:http>
```

How to do this in grails?

I've tried (and other modifications)

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = true
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 8080
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 8443
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderName = 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderValue = 'http'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderName = 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderValue = 'https'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
            '/**':               'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
    ]
```

but still no sucess.

Comment: Have you tried using `plugins` instead of `plugin` in the configuration keys? They've updated to singular form only in the recent milestone and RC versions - you didn't specify which version of the plugin you are using but this would be a simple thing to try.

Comment: Since you are using tomcat, you need to configure tomcat to redirect http to https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working now by removing the first config

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 8080
grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 8443
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderName = 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderValue = 'http'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderName = 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderValue = 'https'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
        '/**':               'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
]
```

and test locally by `grails run-app -https`

For the development server, I just replaced 8080 by 80 and 8443 by 443 in the config.

Comment: Have you looked at sundir's solution?

Comment: Nope, I never touch the web.xml

Answer (score -1):

Yo do not configure Grails to redirect from http to https, but you configure tomcat to automatically redirect from http to https.

You will need to make following changes to your tomcat configuration.

- Enable https connectors in server.xml
- Modify http connectors to redirect to https

Server.xml

```
<Connector port="80" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="443"/>
```

In your web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```